# How can I send the output of commit revision version in email using blat?

Tags: svn, blat

I am sending an email once the svn commit is successful.

Now I want to send the committed revision number (output of svn status -u) also in the email.

I am using the blat to send an email in a batch file.

```
blat - -body "Subversion Commit successful. Log file: \\%computername%%OUTPUT_FILE%" -subject "Successful - SVN Commit'" -to xyz@a.com.
```

Please do let me know how can I send an committed revision number in an email.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the post-commit script in your repositories hook directory:

just place a **post-commit.bat** file there, and put in your blat command. Note: You have to use full pathnames to all execuables, as your PATH environment is empty.

Subversion will call your script after each commit and passes 2 arguments:

- The path to your repository as %1%
- The commited revision number as %2%